# Replace line with file content using sed

Tags: sed, sh

I'm trying to replace a single line in a file with the content of another file, and print the result.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

echo "a
b
c" > template.txt
echo "Hello, World!" > foo.txt

sed -e '/b/ {
  d
  r /dev/stdin
}' "template.txt" < "foo.txt"
```

Unfortunately this results in

```
a
c
```

and when I remove the `d` line in the sed script, I can get

```
a
b
Hello, World
c
```

How can I get rid of the `b` and preserve `Hello, World`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, ToxicFrog, for the answer. Apparently, `d` means "clear pattern space and proceed immediately to next line", so I need these commands in the opposite order. `r` appends the contents of the file to the output immediately rather than reading it into the pattern space.

```
sed -e '/b/ {
  r /dev/stdin
  d
}' "template.txt" < "foo.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/b/cHello World!' file
```

Change (`c`) any line containing `b` to  `Hello World!`.